# how to fix 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'' while using re.fullmatch

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

im trying to check if the user input is matched by the regex of a card
in theory [(2-9)|(10)|(AKQJ)][HCSD]
actually "[(2-9)|(10)|(AKQJ)][HCSD]"

deleting and retyping all whitespase
commeniting out fullmatch line (no more errors)
every combonation of ( and [ that might be nessasary
removing the non or related parts of the regex
splitting the if statement from fullmatch
checked how regex worked but missed that it was a sting and it needed quotes

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from re import fullmatch
def cardCheck(card):
    x = 1
    #if fullmatch([2-9|(10)|AKQJ][HCSD],card) == None:
    if x == 1:
        match = fullmatch((([2-9]|[(10)])|[AKQJ]),card)
        #return "False"
        return False
    else:
        return True
while True:
    card = input("enter the name of the card")
    if card == exit:
        break()
    card = card.upper()
    if cardCheck(card):
        print (card, "is a valid card")
```

i expected card, "is a valid card" for KC, 9D, 10S, expected 11H, 0s, 23H to have no output
 actual output was either

```
return False
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or

```
    match = fullmatch((([2-9]|[(10)])|[AKQJ][HCSD]),card)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'
depending on what version i tried
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex is a string. It must be enclosed in quotation marks: `"([2-9]|[(10)])|[AKQJ]"`. The "invalid syntax" error happens because of the same missing quotes.